# Ruby on Rails: How to extract URL parameter and insert the value inside a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I need to extract a parameter from my url and insert it into my database for a referral system.

Let's say this user, which is `id = 1` has shared his link with another user, the url would be:

`https://www.example.com/signup?referredBy=1`

When the new user creates his account, I want the field `referredBy` to be assigned with the value from the `referredBy` parameter, which should be an Integer.

I've tried to do

`@user.referredBy = [:referredBy]`

But it didn't worked out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you so much.

**EDIT**

My `index.html.erb` is:

```
<% if current_user %>
  Logged in as <%= current_user.nomeUsuario %>
  <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %>
<% end %>

<p id=”notice”><%= notice %></p>

<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %>
  <%= link_to "Log in", login_path %> 
<% end %>
```

My `new.html.erb` is:

```
<h1>New User</h1>

<% if current_user %>
  <% controller.redirect_to root_url %>
<% else %>
  
  <%= render 'form', user: @user %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', login_url %>
<% end %>
```

My `_form.html.erb` is:

```
<%= form_with(model: user) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% user.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, "Full Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :nomeUsuario %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, "E-mail" %>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, "Password" %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, "Password Confirmation" %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, "Tipo do Plano" %>
    <%= form.select :tipoPlano, ["Gratuito", "Mensal", "Anual"], selected: "Gratuito" %>
  </div>

  <%= form.hidden_field :indicadoPor, params[:indicadoPor] %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My `user_controller.rb` is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users or /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    set_tipoPlano
    @user.indicadoPor = params[:indicadoPor]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: "User was successfully created." }
        format.json { render root_url, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1 or /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        set_tipoPlano
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :nomeUsuario, :tipoPlano, :valorPlano, :indicadoPor, :comissaoAcumuladaAtual, :comissaoASerRetirada)
    end

    def set_tipoPlano
      if(@user.tipoPlano == "Gratuito")
        @user.valorPlano = 0.0
      
      elsif(@user.tipoPlano == "Mensal")
        @user.valorPlano = 49.90
      
      elsif(@user.tipoPlano == "Anual")
        @user.valorPlano = 39.90
      end
    end
end
```

If you need something else, please let me know! Thank you so much for the help.

**ANSWER BELOW**

I've fixed it.

I just had to change my form to:

`<%= form.hidden_field :indicadoPor, value: params[:indicadoPor] %>`

I forgot the `=`, so the form wasn't being rendered. Also, I've removed the `@user.referredBy = params[:referredBy]` from my controller. Everything is fine now.

Thank you guys, gals and non-binaries for the help so far!

Comment: If the url hits one of your controllers, you can access it with `params[:referral]` and assign it from there

Comment: When it hits the signup page you can access it using `params[:referral]` as mentioned above in the comment and then you can assign it to the object and add a hidden field on the form, so when the signup form is submitted you will have that value on the user create action, you can also let it save on the user object automatically. Ignore the link on my first comment which I have deleted it is not relevant for you sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys and gals and non-binaries. But I've tried and it didn't worked. I've edited the post.

Comment: Did you add the hidden field on form?

Comment: It would help if you would post the code from your controller's method rather than just single lines. Minimal is good, but context is also good. Rails uses a concept called 'strong parameters' that filters out request parameters that aren't explicitly allowed. Have you permitted `:referral` in your controller? Check out [the guide on controllers](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: @rmlockerd strong parameters aren't really relevant unless you're performing mass assignment (passing a hash of parameters to the model). If you're taking a single attribute from the params you're really just passing a string or nil.

Comment: True. With only 1-2 lines of code it's hard to know what's really going on, so I was guessing at what else might be in there, which was probably inappropriate.

Comment: Okay, I've done some progress, but it still doesn't work. I've added a hidden field and the variable is being assigned in my controller, however, now the console is telling me "Unpermitted parameter".

Comment: I've edited the main post with more information.

Comment: Is user's field called `referral` or `referredBy`?

Comment: I just need to set my variable `referredBy` to the value of my param `referredBy` on the url. find_by won't find a user and give me all their info (name, email, etc.)? The user field is called `referredBy`.

Comment: Ah, finally _some_ consistency with your naming (RE your recent edits). If `referredBy` is a simple integer, it should be enough to fix your hidden field, `<%= form.hidden_field :referredBy, params[:referredBy] %>`. JFYI, this casing is unidiomatic in ruby. Should be `referred_by` instead.

Comment: I am really sorry. I'm translating my code from Portuguese and that caused me some confusion. Snake Case is the default in Ruby, right? I am coming from C/C++, didn't knew that! Thank you so much. By the way, I've did that and now it's telling me `no implicit conversion of String into Hash`.

Comment: Well, this means something else is broken. At this point, to help you any further I'd need to see a [mcve] (like a stripped down rails app with just this controller/action and related views).

Comment: And yes, identifiers for methods and variables should use snake case. Check out the style guide: https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide

Comment: I've edited the main post. If it's not good enogh or you need more code, I am sorry and please let me know what's missing so I can provide more code. Thank you so much for the help until now. It is not translated, so my variables have different names.

Comment: @k1tsunee I meant an actual tiny rails app that I can run myself and see the problem. In a github repository, for example. If you're going to do it, make sure that the app reproduces the problem and steps to reproduce are described in the README.md (for example, "1) click New User button 2) Fill out the form with these values, 3)..."

Comment: I've fixed it, and it was so dumb, lol. Thank you @SergioTulentsev for your help and patience. I'll make sure to make a more objective and standardized question next time. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

```rb
[:referral]
```

This is an array with a single value. That value is a symbol `:referral`.
I'm not sure what type your referredBy column is but it's almost certainly going to complain about being given an array of symbols.

You want

```rb
params[:referral]
```

params is a hash like object containing the params in the url/(and sometimes body). So `params[:referral]` looks up the `:referral` symbol in the params hash and returns whatever the user provided.